# How can i set a token in flutter app and get it in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I want to open flutter webview to show reports from my flutter app so that for each report I do not have to release a new app built. For this, I want to receive token from the login inside the app to the webview so that I can use it on the web for authentication when redirecting from app to web. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What are you using for back-end, Firebase provides these tokens and stuff.

Comment: @nibukdk93 Can you explain more how firebase dB can be used here. How will firebase identify which user token I'll fetch?

Comment: For each auth operations, firbase provides information like usernanme, id, auth.status and so much its better to checkout tutorial or docs, but it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the token in URL of your web app using *query parameters* or by using *Headers*.

Then, you can retrieve the respective token in your web application and perform actions based on it.

Also have a look at [beamer](https://pub.dev/packages/beamer#quick-start).